Clang not assembling double-precision FP register names like $d0
LLVM noob here.  I just built LLVM for MIPS (cross-compiler).
However, it isn't compiling double precision registers ($d%u) in assembler-level.
MIPS version is MIPSII.
My target CPU has 32x 32-bit floating point registers.
So, I want to use $d0~$d15 as double precision registers.  ($d0 is composed of $f0 and $f1)
My environment:  x86-64 Rocky Linux 8.7 (Green Obsidian)
I built LLVM (version 18.0.0, cross-compiler) with:
$ cd <llvm-path>
$ git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git
$ cd llvm-project
$ cmake -S llvm \
   -B build \
   -G "Unix Makefiles" \
   -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;lld" \
   -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
   -DLLVM_TARGET_TO_BUILD=Mips \
   -DLLVM_USE_LINKER=lld \
   -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
   -DLLVM_BUILD_BENCHMARKS=ON \
   -DLLVM_DEFAULT_TARGET_TRIPLE=mips-unknown-linux-gnu \
   -DLLVM_TARGET_ARCH=mips
$ cmake --build build

Test assembler code:
# asm.S
main:
    add.d $d0, $d1, $d2

Compile command:
$ <llvm-path>/llvm-project/build/bin/clang -c asm.S

gives me an error:
asm.S:2:8: error: invalid operand for instruction
 add.d $d0, $d1, $d2
       ^


LLVM can assemble the same instruction written with $f registers fine,
and is how llvm-objdump disassembles:
add.d $f0, $f2, $f4

but I want to use $d registers in assembly.

I tried adding options -mfp32 and -march=mips2 when assembling, but didn't work.
Am I missing some LLVM configure options or compiler options?
The LLVM source code has some mentions of D0-D15:
In the file llvm-project/llvm/lib/Target/Mips/MipsRegisterInfo.td, AFGR64 register set and AFGR64Opnd are defined, consisting of registers D0~D15. This AFGR64Opnd is used in lib/Target/Mips/MipsInstrFPU.td, as a source operand for multiclass ADDS_M's def _32. In the same file, ADDS_M is used to define FADD instruction, which takes add.d as a asm string.
So, I'm wondering why clang does not recognize $d synonyms.

add.d   $f0, $f2, $f4 works as you say, and that's what llvm-objdump -d prints. I wouldn't be surprised if Clang simply doesn't support the $d synonyms for register names.  It's not a question of target feature support, rather asm syntax.
